# Faces become distorted, strange and look glitchy when looking through camera view

Tags: rendering

Whenever I attempt to create a test render (F12) or when I switch to camera view (Numb 0) my models faces look distorted.  When I'm not looking through camera view, everything is smooth and normal, regardless of how close I am to the objects.  When I switch to these modes the faces become distorted, strange and look glitchy.  I've tried a couple things and have no clue what is causing this or what I can do to fix it.

One possible explanation I came up with is that the models have too much information inside of them, and the render isn't sure what to display.  To solve this, I figured I could delete all of the vertices, faces, etc. inside of the model, but I found no way to do this.  I'm at a loss.

Below is a screenshot from the work window in object mode followed by a screenshot of the camera viewpoint.

[image: Object mode]

[image: camera view]

Comment: It looks like Z-fighting, probably the clip distances is set to a very large number.  The crucial piece of information is missing from your screen shots: what are the clip ranges for the 3d view and the the camera for the camera?

Comment: I had my clipping set from 0-100 mm.  I fiddled with it a bit, and with the lower bound at 0.01 it works perfectly.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. :)

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79883/strange-graphics-glitch-when-working-with-very-small-unitsmilimeters/79914#79914

Answer (score 5):

It looks like Z-fighting, probably the clip distances is set to a very large number.

The clip range should encompass your scene, not the whole universe. A large clip range will result in lower depth precision, creating Z-fighting, where the render engine cannot determine which surface is in front or which one is behind. In other words blender cannot tell apart faces that are parallel but in close proximity with each other.

For more info read these links:

[Shadows along edges of mesh in 3D View](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/shadows-along-edges-of-mesh-in-3d-view/1387#1387)

[Weird Tears in terrain mesh in Render View only](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44500/weird-tears-in-terrain-mesh-in-render-view-only/45938#45938)

[Weird shading effects when rendering at long distance](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21647/weird-shading-effects-when-rendering-at-long-distance/21759#21759)

Answer (score 1):

Select your camera, go to the *Properties Panel* on the right and click the green camera *Object Data* properties icon. Under the *Lens* dropdown, adjust *Clip Start* and *End*. This may remove the glitchy appearance.