# Blender 2.91.0 choppy model in viewport when using perspective view?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I have a problem.
In my viewport, model shows as choppy broken model when I m in perspective view. When I change to orthographic view, it shows fine.
Here is the comparison.

But in rendering view, both perspectives are rendered fine.

Is this a bug or anything wrong in my settings?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That appears to be [z-fighting.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) Please read these related posts as well: [Why Faces eat each other?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140119/why-faces-eat-each-other) and [How do I avoid rendering glitches from overlapping faces?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-do-i-avoid-rendering-glitches-from-overlapping-faces)

Comment: This do not happens while rendering, it only happens in viewport and in prespective view. Orthographic view is fine. 
I understand when two faces overlap then this happens but in my case, the area that is not everlapped also shows wierd in viewport. but rendering is fine

Comment: If the linked questions do not solve your problem, then please [edit] your question and explain how. "Closed" does not mean cannot be reopened, you may add a copy of the [project file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) or anything else you feel that is needed to help explain. From the image in your question now, it appears to be overlapping faces, likely a duplicate of the shoe object which would cause the z-fighting.