# What causes the mesh to look like there is another mesh underneath?

Tags: mesh

[image]

I don't know, what causes my objects to look like they are torn.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Faces eat each other?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140119/why-faces-eat-each-other) https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1386/32374

Comment: They will go away if you tweak the viewport clipping start and end value.